# Private key encryption method wanted

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, private-key

I am programming some server-client software and wanted some encryption. Both the server and client share a private key which is fixed length. Haven't decided what length I am going to have the key, but I do know that the key will be between 1 and 32 characters. The key is predetermined (so for instance I may decide I want the key to be abc1234)

I am programming in Java and need the algorithm to be a quick as possible as the clients are most likely to be mobile devices. I don't need any compression but I would prefer if the encrypted string wasn't larger.

I am not looking for top-notch encryption here obviously, but it is my understanding that any key based encryption can't be broken without knowledge of the private key anyway.

Can anyone recommend me an algorithm/method for encryption/decryption with a shared private key?

Comment: *`but it is my understanding that any key based encryption can't be broken without knowledge of the private key anyway.`* This is not true. Many encyption algorithms (that were used in the past) can be broken without previous knowledge of the private key. Especially if the key is small.

Comment: @Ben: Out of curiosity, why must the scheme use an explicitly shared key? Why not just use TLS/SSL?

Comment: @SimonJ: Errr, I don't really know to be honest, for some reason I completely missed the ball on that one. If I use SSL there is no chance of packet sniffing or finding out what is being transferred and all the encryption stuff is managed by Java - is that correct? If it is, it looks like I should be using SSL rather than doing it manually. What are the disadvantages of SSL; if any at all?

Comment: @SimonJ: Also, won't that mean I'd have to deal with certificates and things like that and the user would have to generate their own certificate to run the software?

Comment: TLS/SSL is the easiest approach to *get right*, since Java takes care of algorithm choice, padding, block cipher modes, key negotiation and so on. You'll need a server certificate so clients can ensure they're talking directly to the server, avoiding man-in-the-middle attacks; not verifying server certificates is probably **the** most common flaw in code using TLS/SSL. You *can* use certificates to identify clients, but it's not essential if you have another way (e.g. username/password).

Comment: I've decided to do it manually using the AES encryption as it looks more difficult/interesting. The project I am working on is simply a learning exercise for me. I just wanted to say thank you for the discussion/guidance SimonJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*it is my understanding that any key based encryption can't be broken without knowledge of the private key anyway*

That's not even close to true. A lousy algorithm absolutely can be broken without knowledge of the private key.

Anyhow, if there's a shared key, consider [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

And read up on the [JCE/JCA](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) as Java can do AES and other types of encryption out of the box.  **Much** better than rolling your own.

Comment: Will AES be computationally expensive on devices like Blackberry and Android? Does reducing the key length mean it will be "faster" at decrypting/encrypting? (but obviously making it less secure)